# Azure REST WebClient PUT Blob

Tags: rest, azure, webclient, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to simply upload a new blob to an Azure Storage countainer using WebClient like this :

```
var sas = "[a new generated sas with Read, Write, List & Delete permissions]";
var sData = "This is a test!";
var sEndPoint = "http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/MyTest.txt" + sas;

var clt = new WebClient();
var res = await clt.UploadStringTaskAsync(sEndPoint, "PUT", sData);
```

This is giving me a "(400) Bad Request." error.  Am I doing anything wrong here?

Thanks

(By the way, I need to use REST instead of Client API since I'm in a Silverlight project)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to define a request header (`x-ms-blob-type`) for blob type and set it's value to `BlockBlob`. Also for `Put` requests you would need to define the `Content-Length` request header as well. I wrote a blog post on Shared Access Signatures and performing some blob operations using that (with both REST API and Storage Client library) which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/13/revisiting-windows-azure-shared-access-signature/.

and here's the code from that post on uploading blob. It uses HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse instead of WebClient:

```
static void UploadBlobWithRestAPISasPermissionOnBlobContainer(string blobContainerSasUri)
{
    string blobName = "sample.txt";
    string sampleContent = "This is sample text.";
    int contentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(sampleContent);
    string queryString = (new Uri(blobContainerSasUri)).Query;
    string blobContainerUri = blobContainerSasUri.Substring(0, blobContainerSasUri.Length - queryString.Length);
    string requestUri = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}/{1}{2}", blobContainerUri, blobName, queryString);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
    request.Method = "PUT";
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
    request.ContentLength = contentLength;
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sampleContent), 0, contentLength);
    }
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!  That works like a charm.  But I'd like to do it with a WebClient so I can await the function.  Is there a way to do it?  I tried to set the Content-Length from WebClient but I read that this is  a restricted parameter for WebClient.  Is there any way to work it around?

Comment: Ok, I got it finally.  it's working (with WebClient) without specifying the Content-Length and Content-Type.  I was just missing the "x-ms-blob-type" = "BlockBlob" in my code :)  Thanks

Comment: That's what I was about to say :) that you don't need to specify Content-Length when using WebClient.

Answer (score 1):

When testing against the blob emulator this is the code I need to get it working:

```
        var connection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureStorageConnectionString"];
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connection);

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
        client.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-02-12");
        client.UploadData(string.Format(@"{0}/$root/{1}{2}", storageAccount.BlobEndpoint, myFileName, sharedAccessSignature), "PUT", _content);
```